# SQL Server - notify 30,15, 7 days from time

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to right an SQL Query that will do the following task:

Example:

```
ExpirationDate =  '2018-04-30 00:00:00.000'
```

when the property is  set to expire in 30 days ... 1 month before, I want SQL Server to email me informing that the item is about to expire based upon (Expirationdate)

could someone please give me some pointers as to where I go next... this is what I have tried so far.. 
the query below will find the item however I now want SQL Server Agent to send me an email for each row that is returned, not when nothing is returned

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Property]
WHERE expirationdate <= DateAdd(day ,30 , GetDate())

Comment: Think first. You want the agent to act every day? Including holidays and weekends? Or just "business days". Let's assume every day. So you need to find rows where expiration date (note - date, not datetime - that matters) is (i.e., equals) today + 30 days. Correct? Now play with some code and use some sample data that has expiration dates on and around that particular date. Once you get the query correct, you can then think about the email piece.

Comment: is this correct  SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Property] 
WHERE pexpirationdate <= DateAdd(day ,30 , GetDate())
sorry i am new to sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an excellent link on how to email results from a sql server job agent:

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/send-query-results-sql-server-agent-job/

As for your query:  I wouldn't SELECT *.  Explicitly select the columns you want returned in your email response.

Next I would define a variable to hold the value of your cutoff, this will prevent you doing a calculation for each row within the query.  Example:

```
DECLARE @day30UpperBound DATETIME = DATEADD(Day, 31, cast(getdate() as date));
DECLARE @day30LowerBound DATETIME = DATEADD(Day, 30, cast(getdate() as date));
```

Then you can query results with:

```
SELECT explicitColumnList FROM [dbo].[Property] 
WHERE expirationdate BETWEEN @day30LowerBound AND @day30UpperBound
```

This specific example should give you those Properties with an expiration date that fall in the window of 30 days from current at midnight, to 31 days from current at midnight - so a full 24 hour window 30 days from current day.

You can easily reproduce this for your 15 day, and 7 day reports.  You could put all 3 reports into one job agent.  Or you could make a different job for each of the 3.

You'll have to research a little on how to do only business days if that's what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help. i saved all the results in the csv file and send the email through send mail task and schedule the sql agent jobs to run daily.